# How to prove an estimator is minimax

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation, bayes-theorem, decision-theory

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid sample from $U(\theta-1/2,\theta+1/2)$, consider the absolute loss $L(\theta,a)=|\theta-a|$, $\theta\in(-\infty,+\infty)$, $a\in(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Show that $\delta(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{2}(\min x_i+\max x_i)$ is the minimax estimator of $\theta$.

I've skipped two questions of it, which I have already solved. And the above is the third one. What I have done is that I found a sequence of prior $\Pi_\alpha(\theta)$ being $U(-\alpha,\alpha)$, and its Bayes solution $\delta_{\Pi_\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}(\max\{x_{(n)}-1/2,-\alpha\}+\min\{x_{(1)}+1/2,\alpha\})$, and I also show that this Bayes solution $\delta_{\Pi_\alpha}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}(\min x_i+\max x_i)$. But I have no idea how to calculate the Bayes risk of  $\delta_{\Pi_\alpha}$,and then I can use the Thm2 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_estimator to solve this problem.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the corollary from Theorem 1 on that page (Bayes estimator with constant risk is minimax).

We first have to show that $\frac{1}{2}[\min\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n+\max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n]$ is a Bayes estimator.

We can't do this using a proper prior, but using $\pi(\theta)\propto 1$, we can get a proper posterior distribution:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P[\theta | \{X_i\}_{i=1}^n] &= \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i I_{(x_i \in [\theta-\frac{1}{2},\theta+\frac{1}{2}])})}{\prod_{i=1}^n(x_i I_{(x_i \in [\theta-\frac{1}{2},\theta+\frac{1}{2}])})(\max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n - \min\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n)}\\
& = \frac{1}{(\max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n - \min\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n)}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Which integrates to $1$ only for $\theta \in [\min\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n,\max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n]$. Thus $\theta|\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n \sim \textrm{Unif}(\min\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n,\max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n)$.

Note that $\min_a E_{\Pi(\theta)}[|\theta-a|]$ has a solution $a$ given by the median of $\Pi(\theta)$.

So the specified estimator is a Bayes estimator.

By the corollary, if a Bayes estimator has constant risk it is minimax. Examining the risk, we get:

\begin{equation}
R(\theta,\delta) = E_{\delta}[|\theta-\delta|] = P[\delta<\theta]E_{\delta|\delta<\theta}[\theta-\delta] + p[\delta>\theta]E_{\delta|\delta>\theta}[\delta-\theta]
\end{equation}

Representing 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\delta & = \frac{1}{2}[\min\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n + \max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n]\\
& = \theta - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}[\min\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n + \max\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Where $U_i$ are iid $Unif(0,1)$ random variables. The order statistics are given by: $\min\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n \sim \textrm{Beta}(1,n)$ and $\max\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n \sim \textrm{Beta}(n,1)$.

These two distributions are reflections of each other around $\frac{1}{2}$, which means:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\theta - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}[\min\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n + \max\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Is symmetric about $\theta$; thus $P[\delta<\theta] = P[\delta>\theta]=c$.

Looking at our previous expectation gives us:

\begin{equation}
R(\theta,\delta) = E_{\delta}[|\theta-\delta|] = c(E_{\delta|\delta<\theta}[\theta-\delta] + E_{\delta|\delta>\theta}[\delta-\theta]) = c(E_{\delta|\delta<\theta}[-\delta] + E_{\delta|\delta>\theta}[\delta])
\end{equation}

Which is constant with respect to $\theta$.

Comment: Actually, if the prior is not a proper prior, the theorem "Bayes estimator with constant risk is minimax" may not hold since its proof need to integrate the Risk function with respect to the prior, and an improper prior may make the integral infinity.

Comment: A $\textrm{Gamma}(1,1)$ prior is a proper prior, it just has infinite risk with respect to the prior, but not with respect to the posterior. It's just an $\textrm{Exp}(1)$ prior.